# Send email php in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax

I have such text on the site.
This site use wordpress.

[image]

I now want to download this text using php and send it to my email immediately after loading the page

I have this code, but it does not work

Javascript generates text in these places
HTML:

```
<p id="nameInfo"></p>
<p id="lastNameInfo"></p>
<p id="streetInfo"></p>
```

AJAX: The console displays success, but I do not receive an email

```
$(function(){
var data = {
    name: $("#nameInfo").text(),
    lastName: $("#lastNameInfo").text(),
    message: $("#streetInfo").text()
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sklep/email.php",
    data: data,
    success: function() {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
});
```

PHP:

```
if($_POST){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $message = $_POST['streetInfo'];

    mail("myeiam@gmail.com", $name, $message);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your php code? You seem to be trying to access a parameter named `streetInfo` which doesn't exist in the data object sent to the server

Comment: That's how I tried the console was displaying all the data correctly

Comment: On the PHP when creating the variables put it this way, for example name: isset($_POST['name']) ? utf8_encode($_POST['name']): null; and try again